# Firebase database: High number of calls with minimal data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I built my Firebase database as flat as possible.

This is my structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40115527/3669981
with a little adjustment: Instead of role values in my `projectsRoles` node I'm using the role keys assigned to the `/roles` node (So I can add and edit roles easier).

The pain starts when I need to make **`1 + (numUsers*2)`** Calls in order to get a project member list, assuming I already have the project ID.

1. Call to `projectsRoles/$projectID` to get all user IDS of the current project.
2. Loop each USER ID+Role ID received:

   - Get the role name by `roles/$roleID`
   - get user information by `users/$userID`

That means if a project will have 30 members, the app will make 61 calls to firebase database.

**My question is:** Although the number of calls is high, the data received each call is **minimal**. I followed the instruction to make is as flat as possible, But is it common to make so much calls to firebase?

Comment: Yes, it is quite common to make multiple calls to the database. Unlike what you expect, the number of calls is only minimally affected by the number of calls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good to know about your answer there. thank you.